# Get the parent form element from the first input with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to talk to the parent form element of the first input element with a specific class.
On any given page, I could have at least 2 forms. A login form in my header, and in this case a form in the body of my page.

I am able to find the first element with a class name like this:

```
$('.my-select:first');
```

I thought, getting the parent form would be easy:

```
$('.my-select:first').closest('form');
```

But, it doesn't apear to be the case. When I try this to make sure I'm talking to the correct form:

```
$('.my-select:first').closest('form').attr('id');
```

I am getting back *undefined*.

'closest()' travels up the DOM, so I thought I would be safe. I don't think I'm finding the right selector(s) though. Here is what my markup looks like:

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform">
<fieldset>
<div>
<div>
<label>
<select class="my-select">
    ....
```

I will ultimately have more than one select element with the class name of "my-select". I am going to have a button that will dynamically add another select input. That's why I need to find the closest form element.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your code was correct, but your form has no ID to return.

Comment: According to your HTML, your form does not have an id attribute

Comment: Can you validate your HTML to make sure that all tags are properly closed?

Comment: Yep, I have - I was just trying to keep my question short/simple to show the nesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct, but there is no ID on the form to report

```
<form id="?????">    <====
```

To test your code use the length instead:

```
alert($('.my-select:first').closest('form').length);
```

This should display `1`.

JSFiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/rz1ye80j/

Comment: nice catch - was looking at it and immediately thought "nothing is wrong"

Comment: I should have added that - I do have an id/class/action etc. on it. I was just trying to keep things simple for everyone. I will give this a try. Thank you very much for the Fiddle.